# How to exclude undefined symbols from RapidEars framework linking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, openears

I added a framework to my Xcode 4.4 project by drag-and-drop of the framework onto the project in the Project Navigator.

I am getting linker errors for undefined symbols on Xcode.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_returner", referenced from:
      _should_be_returned in RapidEarsDemo(multisphinx_re.o)
  "_input_sample_rate", referenced from:
      -[PocketsphinxController(RapidEars) startRealtimeListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath:andDictionaryAtPath:] in RapidEarsDemo(PocketsphinxController+RapidEars.o)
      -[ContinuousModel(RapidEars) realtimeListeningLoopWithLanguageModelAtPath:andDictionaryAtPath:] in RapidEarsDemo(ContinuousModel+RapidEars.o)
      -[RECommandArray commandArrayForlanguageModel:andDictionaryPath:isJSGF:] in RapidEarsDemo(RECommandArray.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

I ran "nm" on the RapidEarsDemo framework file, and I only see _input_sample_rate for i386.  How do I specify not to include this symbol for armv7?

"nm" doens't show _returner at all.

In Build Phases -> "Link Binaries with Project", I made sure that my new framework is listed there.  I already did a clean and rebuild.

Any suggestions?  Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know you said framework but is this a library? a .a?

Comment: No, it is a .framework, not a library.

Comment: You are using an old version of OpenEars and updated version of Rapidearsdemo, just update to the current OpenEars version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I included two frameworks.  Framework A referred to framework B.  I was using version 1.1 of A, but version 1.2 of B.  Thus A expected symbols to exist in B, which did not exist in that version.

Running "nm" to list the symbols was enlightening.

Comment: Halle from Politepix here, glad you got this cleared up on your own. To clarify for others who might have a similar issue, RapidEars is a plugin for OpenEars and it has a minimum version of OpenEars that it can be run with.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing some header files of library to include in project.

Comment: Missing headers cause failures during compiling, not during linking.

Answer (score 0):

I would try under Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags add "-all_load"

Comment: Just wanted to mention that for OpenEars and its plugins specifically there is never a need to use -all_load.